# Rerouting ssl command fails during build of application through Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: spring, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, iptables

I have a spring application that I am deploying through Elastic Beanstalk. When running a container command to reroute ssl the build fails. The command I'm trying to run is:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9000

And the traceback is:

*Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_TestApplication: Command 01_reroute_ssl failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 277, in build
changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_reroute_ssl failed
2023-11-27 13:11:27,817 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-11-27 13:11:27,817 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_reroute_ssl failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in 
worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
self.run_config(config, worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 277, in build
changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_reroute_ssl failed*

The platfrom I am building on is : Corretto 17 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.1.1

What is this error caused by? I'm not sure how to decipher the traceback information.